Upgrading a Hive DB in a Flutter App with a new field
TL;DR - I want to support an upgrade of my app to a new version of a db, with a new field. I feel I have tried everythig and cannot find a solution where it gracefully handles the old field reading, as well as the new field reading.
I have an andorid flutter application which stores recipes (in a hive box), within the recipes I have ingredients, this is a cast list that has it's own model and adapter - there is no visible box, it must exists within the recipe box I guess (when viewing via chrome).
I am trying to add a new field and support an upgrade from the old Hive model, but I keep running into errors.
In the original version of my app I had the following code for model and adapter for Ingredients, not there is no preparation field:
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

class Ingredient {
  final String name;
  final String quantity;
  final String unit;

  Ingredient({
    required this.name,
    required this.quantity,
    required this.unit,
  });
}

class IngredientAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Ingredient> {
  @override
  final int typeId = 1; // Unique identifier for the adapter

  @override
  Ingredient read(BinaryReader reader) {
    return Ingredient(
      name: reader.readString(),
      quantity: reader.readString(),
      unit: reader.readString(),
    );
  }

  @override
  void write(BinaryWriter writer, Ingredient obj) {
    writer.writeString(obj.name);
    writer.writeString(obj.quantity);
    writer.writeString(obj.unit);
  }
}

However, when I implemented a new field for ingredients called preparation I kept getting a Range Error with the updated model I was using, following:
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

class Ingredient {
  final String name;
  final String quantity;
  final String unit;
  final String? preparation;

  Ingredient({
    required this.name,
    required this.quantity,
    required this.unit,
    this.preparation,
  });
}

class IngredientAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Ingredient> {
  @override
  final int typeId = 1; // Unique identifier for the adapter

  @override
  Ingredient read(BinaryReader reader) {
    final name = reader.readString();
    final quantity = reader.readString();
    final unit = reader.readString();
    final preparation = reader.readString();

    return Ingredient(
      name: name,
      quantity: quantity,
      unit: unit,
      preparation: preparation,
    );
  }

  @override
  void write(BinaryWriter writer, Ingredient obj) {
    writer.writeString(obj.name);
    writer.writeString(obj.quantity);
    writer.writeString(obj.unit);
    writer.writeString(obj.preparation ?? '');
  }
}

So I adjusted the model and adapter for ingredients and the old data loads, and I am able to populate the new field preparation:
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

class Ingredient {
  final String name;
  final String quantity;
  final String unit;
  final String? preparation;

  Ingredient({
    required this.name,
    required this.quantity,
    required this.unit,
    this.preparation,
  });
}

class IngredientAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Ingredient> {
  @override
  final int typeId = 1; // Unique identifier for the adapter

  @override
  Ingredient read(BinaryReader reader) {
    final name = reader.readString();
    final quantity = reader.readString();
    final unit = reader.readString();
    String? preparation;

    return Ingredient(
      name: name,
      quantity: quantity,
      unit: unit,
      preparation: preparation,
    );
  }

  @override
  void write(BinaryWriter writer, Ingredient obj) {
    writer.writeString(obj.name);
    writer.writeString(obj.quantity);
    writer.writeString(obj.unit);
    writer.writeString(obj.preparation ?? '');
  }
}

However, when I restart the app I get a RangeError not enough bytes available when it is trying to read ingredients with the new preparation field.
So,I thought I could create a hybrid solution to read it if it exists, or move on with a null if it doesn't (like above)... using the following code:
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

class Ingredient {
  final String name;
  final String quantity;
  final String unit;
  late String? preparation;

  Ingredient({
    required this.name,
    required this.quantity,
    required this.unit,
    this.preparation,
  });
}

class IngredientAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Ingredient> {
  @override
  final int typeId = 1; // Unique identifier for the adapter

  @override
  Ingredient read(BinaryReader reader) {
    final name = reader.readString();
    final quantity = reader.readString();
    final unit = reader.readString();
    String? preparation;

    try {
      preparation = reader.readString(); // Try reading the preparation field
    } catch (_) {
      //String? preparation;
    }

    return Ingredient(
      name: name,
      quantity: quantity,
      unit: unit,
      preparation: preparation,
    );
  }

  @override
  void write(BinaryWriter writer, Ingredient obj) {
    writer.writeString(obj.name);
    writer.writeString(obj.quantity);
    writer.writeString(obj.unit);
    writer.writeString(obj.preparation ?? '');
  }
}

This resulted in HiveError (HiveError: Cannot read, unknown typeId: 246. Did you forget to register an adapter?).
My main.dart has stayed pretty consistent throughout, I read somewhere declaring the model associated with the adapter would help, but it didn't. Here is the main function my app:
void main() async {
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  Hive.registerAdapter<Recipe>(RecipeAdapter());
  Hive.registerAdapter(GroceryAdapter());
  Hive.registerAdapter<Ingredient>(IngredientAdapter());
  Hive.registerAdapter(SettingsModelAdapter());

  await Hive.openBox<Recipe>('recipes');
  await Hive.openBox<Grocery>('groceries');
  await Hive.openBox<SettingsModel>('settings'); // Open the settings box

  ThemeMode initialThemeMode =
      await _getInitialThemeModeFromHive() ?? ThemeMode.system;
  final initialSortCriteria =
      await _getInitialSortCriteriaFromHive() ?? SortCriteria.dateAdded;
  final initialSortMethod =
      await _getInitialSortMethodFromHive() ?? SortMethod.descending;

  if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    MobileAds.instance.initialize();
  }
  runApp(MyApp(
    initialThemeMode: initialThemeMode,
    initialSortCriteria: initialSortCriteria,
    initialSortMethod: initialSortMethod,
  ));
}

I am at a loss as to how I can add this field and not break the upgrade path, I do not want to clear data. Any ideas?
